# How to write feature types with different geometries using Schema(From Table) to FME FileGDB using FME?

Tags: fme-form, translation

I need to generate a geodatabase with 25 feature classes according to varying schema (geometry included) that are defined in an excel spreadsheet. My approach so far has to been to use the Schema Reader(From Table) and the FileGDB dynamic writer. However, when I run the workspace it returns a single feature class, despite the fact that I have dynamic schema enabled and specified to define feature classes based on the input table.

**EDIT: I used the parameters as shown below and was returned unique geodatabase tables, however they did not carry the geometry specified in the input schema.**

Is there an additional transformer needed to run this type of translation? Obviously I do not want to fan out by feature type because that only allows one geometry type.

See below for sample of input schema:[image]

[image]

Comment: First do you have ArcGIS installed on the same PC? (This installs the ArcObject libraries that are required to do this correct) FileGDB OpenAPI has limitations - FME will read/write this correctly if ArcGIS is available.

Comment: Yes, ArcGIS is installed on the same machine. Do I need to use the 32bit version of FME? Currently using 2015.0 x64.

Comment: Still not working using 32 bit version. It looks as though the workspace is not properly finding the geometry type and feature name, which is strange because that is specified within the schema reader.

Comment: I've tried doing this before.  The issue I had was that I didn't have any features to add to the geodatabase and I couldn't create blank feature classes.  I ended up writing the lines of the spreadsheet to the feature classes and then deleting them manually.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your dynamic parameters? It occurs to me that these are the likely problem. Maybe there is another Reader in the workspace and it is using that for the source schema. Alternatively, the suggestion that you aren't sending any actual features to the Writer is one to check out.

Comment: I got a little further today - see edit in question. My workaround was to write to shapefiles in batches for each geometry type and then import the outputs I need to geodatabase feature classes.